# Pixel C reports wrong Orientation in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a function I use to read the orientation for my app in Xamarin and it works on other devices by Google and Samsung but not the Pixel C.

```
        public DeviceOrientations GetOrientation()
    {
        IWindowManager windowManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();

        var rotation = windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
        bool isLandscape = rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90 || rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270;
        return isLandscape ? DeviceOrientations.Landscape : DeviceOrientations.Portrait;
    }
```

Can any one advise how I go about getting the Pixel C resolved? Or is this something on the Xamarin side that must be resolved?

****UPDATE****
I made the changes per the answer and have included it here.

```
            IWindowManager windowManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
        bool isLandscape = false;
        Android.Graphics.Point aSize = new Android.Graphics.Point();
        windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetSize(aSize);

        if (aSize.X > aSize.Y)
        {
            isLandscape = true;
        } else
        {
            isLandscape = false;
        }
        return isLandscape ? DeviceOrientations.Landscape : DeviceOrientations.Portrait;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotation is defined to be the orientation relative to the "default" orientation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation()). The Pixel C has a different "default" than what you're expecting.

I usually use getSize() (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)) and then compare the width and height to determine if I'm in portrait or landscape.

Comment: Thank you - I will update it with my code changes for everyone else that runs across this.